# Is there a single HTML5/CSS3 compatibility test, as an alternative to testing individual features?

Tags: html, css

I have been given a website and I need to display a popup if the browser does not support any of the features used as it is built with CSS 3 and HTML 5. The only issue is I do not know if there is a catch all method to check if a browser cannot parse something or would I need to use something like Modernizr and check every element and feature individually?

Comment: Thanks Chad, but I mean is there something you can run as a catch all on the actual website without having to check every individual item with caniuse and modernizer

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "a catch all method to check if a browser cannot parse something". Cannot parse what?

Comment: @Max: catch all *what*? All HTML5 and CSS3 features? There isn't one test for all of them.

Comment: I'm not aware of a single tool or plugin that can do this, but the goal of modernizr is to render a page consistently across browsers, tl;dr to allow html5 and css3 features in old browsers. If you utilize modernizr and allow it to work, then you shouldn't have to worry about non-compatibility, except for some extreme edge cases.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-detect-css-support-in-browsers-with-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

> if there is a catch all method to check if a browser cannot parse something

*Parsing* runs on pretty generic rules. Unknown elements get added to the DOM. Unknown attributes get added to the DOM. CSS properties or values of properties that are not recognised are ignored. Rulesets associated with CSS selectors with unknown components are ignored. Assignments to JavaScript properties are assigned with no special handling of them.

About the only things you could catch (using `try / catch`) would be attempts to call functions that don't exist, and attempts to access properties of non-existent objects.

So, no, there isn't a generic solution. You need to test for everything that might cause a critical failure separately.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I think you're asking whether there's a single test to identify browsers that don't support *any* HTML5/CSS3 features (so that you know there's no point testing for support of individual features).

In short: there isn't.

"HTML5" and "CSS3" each refer to loose groups of features that aren't particularly related, aside from the fact that they weren't in the HTML 4 or CSS 2.1 specs. There isn't any root property or feature or thing you can check to tell you whether there's *any* HTML5/CSS3 support. It's just a series of additional features that are individually there or not.

Browser detection might be your best bet. Have a look at your site's browser stats, and see what the most common browsers are that don't support any HTML5/CSS3 features (I'll take a wild, shot-in-the-dark guess that it'll be IE8/7/6). Then write/get (e.g. from [jQuery's deprecated `browser` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)) a detect for those browsers.

If the user is using one of them, show the popup. If not, test for individual features before using them.

Eventually, the old browsers that don't support anything won't be used enough to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  No, there is no test that will magically look at every bit of code in your site and tell you which ones will not work in certain browsers without some effort on your end.

That's the entire point of tools like Modernizr - to be able to test for various CSS3/HTML5 features and whether the browser in use supports them.  Modernizr is just a collection of one-off tests for specific features, you can test for as many or as few as you like and adjust your code with polyfills, etc accordingly to account for lack of compatibility for whatever you're using.  There is no magic solution to this beyond that.

You need to identify all of the CSS3, HTML5 etc features that might not be supported in older browsers in your site code and use a tool like Modernizr to test whether they work in the client browser and use the results of those tests to determine whether to display a modal and what to put on it.